# Syntax Error after copying code to eclipse on another computer with java eclipse

Tags: java, events, syntax, queue

I copied the following line of code in a new installed version of eclipse on my laptop (linux mint).
On my desktop-Windows system it works.
My system library on linux is java-8-openjdk-amd64.
Compiler comliance level is 1.7.
Is there anything else I can do?

[image: e]

Comment: Looks like this instance of eclipse is using a version of Java < 8.

Comment: Thank you i downloaded the latest eclipse and it works now